# Self-energy of a spinon coupled to a $\rm U(1)$ gauge field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, non-equilibrium, self-energy

I would like to understand how to calculate the 1-loop self-energy for spinons coupled to a $\rm U(1)$ gauge field. For context, I am going through Nagaosa & Lee's "Gauge theory of the normal state of high-Tc superconductors" and Nave & Lee's "Transport Properties of a spinon Fermi surface coupled to a $\rm U(1)$ gauge field".

The action is given as:
$$S = \int d\tau \int d^2r f_\sigma^* (\partial_\tau - ia_0 -\mu_f)f_\sigma - \frac{1}{2m_f}f_\sigma^*(\partial_j +ia_j)^2 f_\sigma $$
where $f_\sigma$ is a fermionic field.

From my rudimentary understanding of QFT, the self-energy for the $f$ particles should look like
$$\Sigma \sim \int d^2 q d\nu G(k+q, \omega+\nu) D(q, \nu)$$
based on the Feynman diagram. However, I see that the expression in the aforementioned references involves the boson distribution function $n(\nu)$:
$$\Sigma^< \sim  \sum_q\int d\nu |\vec{k}\times \vec{q}/|q||^2 \text{Im}D(q,\nu) \left[(n(\nu)+1) G^<(k+q, \omega+\nu) + n(\nu)G^<(k+q, \omega+\nu)\right]$$

How do I see where this comes from?

Comment: This may be a very basic comment. I have not checked the particular paper in detail but those factors usually come when you perform a [Matsubara sum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency), which you do when you’re calculating such quantities at non zero temperatures, have you checked that?